# How can I block postback caused by an ASP.NET Button?

Tags: asp.net, postback

How can I block postback caused by an ASP.NET Button (or, any other) server control?

I.e. I shall push a Button but no postback will occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;")
```

on page load.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

property of the button

Comment: oops I was focused on the button. Slipped my mind that he wanted it to work for any control.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:button runat="server" ... OnClientClick="return false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AJAX controls](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) that do callbacks instead of postbacks for another possibility besides the Javascript "return false;" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the client side validation fail for the control's validation group. Depending on what you're trying to do, that might be a nicer solution.

You can piggyback on the JavaScript run for each postback as well, but showing you from the top of my head while typing on a mobile phone... maybe not. I'll update this post when I get home.